# How to populate User defined objects from list of lists in scala

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala.

Currently trying to write a program which fetches table metadata from a database as a list of lists in the below format, and convert it to Objects of user defined type `TableFieldMetadata`.

The `getAllTableMetaDataAsVO` function does this conversion.

Can you tell me if I can write this function much better in functional way.

```
| **Table Name** | **FieldName** | **Data type** |

| table xxxxxx  | field yyyyyy  | type zzzz |

| table xxxxxx  | field wwwww| type mmm|

| table qqqqqq| field nnnnnn| type zzzz |
```

**Note**: Here table name can repeat as it usually has multiple columns.

**User defined classes:**
1. TableFieldMetadata:

```
/**
 * Class to hold the meta data for a table
 */ 
class TableFieldMetadata (name: String){
  var tableName: String = name
  var fieldMetaDataList: List[FieldMetaData] = List()

 def add(fieldMetadata: FieldMetaData) {
    fieldMetaDataList = fieldMetadata :: fieldMetaDataList 
 }
}
```

2. FieldMetaData :

```
/**
 * Class to hold the meta data for a field
 */
class FieldMetaData (fieldName: String, fieldsDataType: String) {
    var name:String = fieldName
    var dataType:String = fieldsDataType
}
```

**Function:**

```
/**
 * Function to convert list of lists to user defined objects
 */
def getAllTableMetaDataAsVO(allTableMetaData: List[List[String]]):List[TableFieldMetadata] = {
  var currentTableName:String = null
  var currentTable: TableFieldMetadata = null;
  var tableFieldMetadataList: List[TableFieldMetadata] = List()

  allTableMetaData.foreach { tableFieldMetadataItem =>
    var tableName = tableFieldMetadataItem.head
    if (currentTableName == null || !currentTableName.equals(tableName)) {
      currentTableName = tableName
      currentTable = new TableFieldMetadata(tableName)
      tableFieldMetadataList = currentTable :: tableFieldMetadataList
    }
    if (currentTableName.equals(tableName)) {
      var tableField = tableFieldMetadataItem.tail
      currentTable.add(new FieldMetaData(tableField(0), tableField(1)))
    }    

  }
  return tableFieldMetadataList
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution. NOTE: I just used `Table` and `Field` for easy of typing into the REPL. You should use case classes.

```
scala> case class Field( name: String, dType : String) 
defined class Field

scala> case class Table(name : String, fields : List[Field])
defined class Table

scala> val rawData = List( List("table1", "field1", "string"), List("table1", "field2", "int"), List("table2", "field1", "string") )
rawData: List[List[String]] = List(List(table1, field1, string), List(table1, field2, int), List(table2, field1, string))

scala> val grouped = rawData.groupBy(_.head)
grouped: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[List[String]]] = Map(table1 -> List(List(table1, field1, string), List(table1, field2, int)), table2 -> List(List(table2, field1, string)))

scala> val result = grouped.map { case(k,v) => { val fields = for { r <- v } yield { Field( r(1), r(2) ) }; Table( k, fields ) } } 
result: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Table] = List(Table(table1,List(Field(field1,string), Field(field2,int))), Table(table2,List(Field(field1,string))))
```

Comment: Thank a lot. It is some thing what I am looking for.